# React scroll-previous-view content

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, vue.js, dom

I have got 10 lists of questions in a single multi-step form. I want to answer the question step by step.

However, I want to go back first one by using previous button. Then, I need to give a button that name is "previous". when user click on the previous button will go to the first question.

```
var items = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  items.push(i);
}

var List = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {index: 0};
  },
  handleShow: function(i) {
    this.setState({index: i});
    this.refs[i].scrollIntoView({block: 'end', behavior: 'smooth'});
  },
  render: function() {
    return(
      <div>
        <ul>{items.map(function(item, i) {return <li ref={i}>{item}</li>})}</ul>
        <button onClick={this.handleShow.bind(this, 0)}>0</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleShow.bind(this, 50)}>50</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleShow.bind(this, 99)}>99</button>
        {this.state.index}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Now, when I click on button 0 , it will go to the 0 and when I click on the 50 , it will go to 50 . Instead of three different buttons, I need to create previous button that's doing all of the things

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is very easy. For previous and next buttons to work, you need to change the code in your render function like so:

```
render: function() {
    return(
      <div>
        <ul>{items.map((item, i) => <li ref={i}>{item}</li>)}</ul>
        <button onClick={this.handleShow.bind(this, this.state.index-1)} disabled={this.state.index===0}>Previus</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleShow.bind(this, this.state.index+1)} disabled={this.state.index===items.length-1}>Next</button>
        {this.state.index}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Notice that I have added `disabled` attribute to both buttons because you will never want your users to go negative index or exceeded index.

If you have further questions, please ask in the comment. Enjoy coding!